# MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to setup an app with mongodb. I apparently need to

```
nano /etc/mongo.conf and uncomment "auth=true"
```

But there is no such setting, I have even checked /etc/mongod.conf and there is no auth=true in there.

So I was told to add user with userAdminAnyDatabase so I went in to the mongo shell and tried

```
db.createUser({ user: "username", pwd: "password", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"] });
```

and I get

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named userAdminAnyDatabase@test
```

All I want to do is either find my admin conn settings or just disable localhost auth altogether and get on with the installation.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this statement in the `admin` database, you are currently running it against the `test` database. Type in `use admin` in the Mongo shell to switch to the admin database. You also need to grant your user the `readWriteAnyDatabase` role.

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
 "username",
[
  { role: "readAnyDatabase", db:"admin" }
]
)
```

Comment: It appears I already have ran the statement in the admin db earlier but your answer is correct in that I was trying to the test.  However when I try connect I get :  error: NodeBB could not connect to your Mongo database. Mongo returned the following error: Authentication failed.  This is with the same credentials I gave it too.

Comment: thanks, how do I grant the readWriteAnyDatabase role in a query?